# How can I set the status bar color for Android L to be completely transparent? (No gray tint)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

This is my style for my app in Android L, values-v21

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

However, the gray tint is still present. How can I have it truly 100% transparent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Just gotta not use TranslucentDecor.

Here's the new styles:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```